# Top message box in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a message-alert box in my web app. I created the main style but I have problems on small screen sizes.

Here's the image for the regular 1366x768 computer screen:
[image]

And here is for a typical mobile device:

[image]

## Problems:

1. The X button has tagled with the message.
2. The main message wrapper has fixed and wasn't expand when the message came out of the wrapper.

How to fix the two above problems? Do I have to follow another path?  I use `position: fixed;` property-value to keep my message on top.

Here are my HTMl and CSS code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="top-msg">
        <div class="top-msg-ico">
            !
        </div>
        <div class="top-msg-inner">
            <p>Only letters and nubers are allowed for email. See <a href="#">security</a> for more info.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="top-msg-close" style="  cursor: pointer;">&#10005;</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-msg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(42,45,50,0.6);
  color: rgba(250,251,255,0.95);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;


}

.top-msg-close {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  //border: 1px solid white;
  //height: 100%;
  width: 3%;

}

.top-msg-inner {
  top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  //border: 1px solid white;


}

.top-msg-ico {
  min-width: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/4oLvyajo/

## UPDATE -SOLUTION!-

After some help from [LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391782/top-message-box-in-css/35392072#35392072) answer I manage to finish all the design, so I accepts his answer but the hole solution is in the fiddle below.

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/4oLvyajo/4/

Images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's probably because your `height` in `.top-msg` is fixed

Comment: ..well I know but this is how I like to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start for you

```css
.top-msg {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(42,45,50,0.6);
  color: rgba(250,251,255,0.95);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.top-msg-close {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 45px;
}

.top-msg-inner a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.top-msg-inner a:hover {
  color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.top-msg-inner {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 110px);
}
.top-msg-ico {
  float: left;
  width: 65px;
  height: 57px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-msg">
  <div class="top-msg-ico">
    !
  </div>
  <div class="top-msg-inner">
    <p>Only letters and nubers are allowed for email. See <a href="#">security</a> for more info.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="top-msg-close" style="cursor: pointer;">&#10005;</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I just finished all the requirements. I edit your code slightly. What should I do? Update y answer? Post my own answer? Send you the finished code to update yours? Cause I don't want to accept your answer while there are things to add.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas An answer is suppose to be a guide, or a how-to, and with that one add one own's adjustments. If my answer solve the main issue and you for example increased the size of your icon, my answer should be selected/accepted. Does that make sense? ... Some people add a comment to the answer they picked and often the answerer update their answer accordingly, based on how much it were altered.

Comment: yeap this is what I did! :) Thank you again!

Comment: @GeorgeGkas Well that was a quite a change compared to my answer. Now I think you better up vote mine (if you like of course), remove your question edit and add that as a self answer and then accept that instead.

Comment: Just update yours wit my code if you want. I doesn't matter anyway, anyone will read my question can find the code from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

replace the `width: 80%` with `margin-right: 40px`, and you'll have to play around with the `top: 15px` as well (at -11 I had it looking right, but you can play around with that)

[Here is the updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4oLvyajo/1/)

If you want everything scalable you'll need a completely different approach. First of all, if you place a right floating element under a block element it will float right, but underneath it. You'll need to define the floating close button element first.

[Anyway, here's the updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4oLvyajo/2/)

It needs some minor tweaks in the padding and margins, but I think this is very close to what you're looking for

Comment: you fixed the close ico problem but what about expanding? Is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: I added the fiddle that'll expand as well